# Print custom compile messages from a file using assembly directives

Tags: gcc, assembly, compilation, directive

I am compiling assembly code using gcc and I would like to print custom messages in the compile procedure which are included from files. I want to be able to do something like this:

```
custommessage:
    .incbin "custommessage.txt"
.print custommessage
```

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do this directly since the `.print` directive only takes strings to print.

However, you can get what you want if you're willing to perform a small transformation on your messages file first:

```
sed -e 's/^/.print \"/' -e 's/$/\"/' custommessage.txt > msg.txt
```

This prepends `.print "` and appends `"` to every line.

Then in your assembly file

```
.include "msg.txt"
```

will print all your messages.